# Silence compiiler warning about @doc on private functions

Tags: elixir

Elixir wants to warn me that my `@doc` annotations won't get copied to the beam file:

```
warning: function foo/1 is private, @doc's are always discarded for private functions
  lib/hello/world.ex:12
```

But I'd rather use `@doc` for all my function documentation instead of switching between `@doc` and `#`.

How can I tell the compiler to stop warning me about this?

Comment: https://elixirforum.com/t/proposal-docp-for-private-function-documentation-and-doctests/3732 but ultimately no, I don't believe there's an option for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to silence compiler warnings.

In the past, people have asked about documenting private functions for use with ExDoc or DocTest. However, this not possible. Per José:

> It is worth remembering that a private function does not exist outside of the module that defines it. You cannot test private functions because you can't invoke a private function outside of the module that defines it.
>
> In fact, the compiler may even remove the private function entirely during compilation. This means a private function only exists when looking at the code and, if you need to look at the code to read it, then it is not documentation.
>
> A private function is, for all purposes, exactly what you defined code comments to be: a temporary or semi-permanent blob which is aimed directly at developers. There is no guarantee it will exist tomorrow, which is why it is private.

Comment: My question was "how do I turn off the compiler warning" and your answer is mostly about why I shouldn't try to generate docs for private functions (which is not something I'm trying to do).

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately my answer is the best I could provide, because if you stop documenting these functions, compiler warnings will gone. I don't know any other solution for that. There's purpose in compiler warnings and we shouldn't ignore them.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot you might want to re-read the answer, since you did not get it at the first attempt. The very first sentence in the clearest way states: “**There is no way to do that**.” If it is not an exact question, I do not know what is.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR It's not possible to silence compiler warnings about @doc for private functions

Reasoning behind it:

> Elixir treats documentation and code comments as different concepts. Documentation is an explicit contract between you and users of your Application Programming Interface (API), be them third-party developers, co-workers, or your future self. Modules and functions must always be documented if they are part of your API.
>
> Code comments are aimed at developers reading the code. They are useful for marking improvements, leaving notes (for example, why you had to resort to a workaround due to a bug in a library), and so forth. They are tied to the source code: you can completely rewrite a function and remove all existing code comments, and it will continue to behave the same, with no change to either its behaviour or its documentation.
>
> Because private functions cannot be accessed externally, Elixir will warn if a private function has a @doc attribute and will discard its content. However, you can add code comments to private functions, as with any other piece of code, and we recommend developers to do so whenever they believe it will add relevant information to the readers and maintainers of such code.

Source: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/writing-documentation.html#documentation-code-comments

Comment: I find it a problem that people in general avoid writing comments to private functions, even though usually the heavy working algorithms are private functions.

Comment: Async communication is issue there. People usually think that someone will ask them to explain but that's not usually the case. Maybe author of the code will no longer be at the company or will be busy at the moment someone needs explanation. I like to put comments where it makes sense.